# Ruby on Rails link_to undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm following the Twitter for Zombies tutorial and i'm having trouble getting the link_to method to work.

In my Tweet controller I have:

```
@tweet = tweet.find(params['id']);
```

In my view i've tried the following:

```
<%= link_to @tweet.zombie.name, @tweet.zombie %>
<%= link_to @tweet.zombie.name, zombie_path(@tweet.zombie) %>
```

But I keep getting the error:

```
undefined method `zombie_path' for #<#<Class:0xab1fd00>:0xa1d5d80>
```

Any ideas whats up with this? Thanks.

Comment: Does it say for which line it's erroring out on? Is it for the first or second link_to?

Comment: I only have one link_to call. It's showing an error on that line.

Comment: Oh I see. Sorry I skimmed over the part you saying you've tried the following. I thought you meant you currently had that in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's in your `routes.rb` file? Please show us.

Do you have the line like this?

```
resources :zombies
```

Comment: This was the problem. I was missing that line. Thanks :)